# error:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:lib(255):func(4095):reason(4095) during RSA decyption

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, rsa, crypt

I'm trying to create a hybrid cryptography tool in C++ with Qt Gui.
(The data will be encrypted with AES 256-CBC, the AES Key RSA encrypted and saved then.)
But the RSA part of this tool doesn't work.
I wrote the sourcecode several times but I always get the same error on decrypt.

`error:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:lib(255):func(4095):reason(4095)`

**I hope someone could help me get a working RSA encrypt + decrypt implementation.**

You can see the sourcecode here or download a testing Qt Project from my dropbox..

Dropbox Download: https://db.tt/6HKsYRTa

Sourcecode 1. Implementation:

```
void MainWindow::rsaEncrypt()
{
    EVP_PKEY *pk = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = NULL;

    QByteArray encrypted = QByteArray();

    //------------------------------------------------
    //--- READ PUBLIC KEY ----------------------------
    FILE *pkFile = fopen(ui->publicKeyPath->text().toStdString().c_str(), "r");
    if(pkFile == NULL) throw NULL;

    pk = PEM_read_PUBKEY(pkFile, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(pk == NULL) throw NULL;
    fclose(pkFile);
    //------------------------------------------------
    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pk, NULL);


    //------------------------------------------------
    //--- ENCRYPT DATA -------------------------------
    int err;

    err = EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init(ctx);
    if(err <= 0) throw NULL;

    err = EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PADDING);
    if(err <= 0) throw NULL;

    size_t outLen = 0;
    err = EVP_PKEY_encrypt(
                            ctx,
                            NULL,
                            &outLen,
                            (uchar*) ui->plainTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().toStdString().c_str(),
                            ui->plainTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().size()
    );
    if(err <= 0) throw NULL;
    encrypted.resize(outLen);

    err = EVP_PKEY_encrypt(
                            ctx,
                            (uchar*) encrypted.data(),
                            &outLen,
                            (uchar*) ui->plainTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().toStdString().c_str(),
                            ui->plainTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().size()
    );
    //------------------------------------------------
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pk);

    if(err > 0) ui->encryptedTextEdit->document()->setPlainText(QString(encrypted));
    else {
            QByteArray errStr = QByteArray();
            errStr.resize(256);
            ERR_load_ERR_strings();
            ERR_error_string(err, errStr.data());
            ui->encryptedTextEdit->document()->setPlainText( QString(errStr) );
    }
}

void MainWindow::rsaDecrypt()
{
    EVP_PKEY *pk = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = NULL;

    QByteArray decrypted = QByteArray();

    //------------------------------------------------
    //--- READ PRIVATE KEY ---------------------------
    FILE *pkFile = fopen(ui->privateKeyPath->text().toStdString().c_str(), "r");
    if(pkFile == NULL) throw NULL;

    pk = PEM_read_PrivateKey(pkFile, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(pk == NULL) throw NULL;
    fclose(pkFile);
    //------------------------------------------------
    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pk, NULL);


    //------------------------------------------------
    //--- DECRYPT DATA -------------------------------
    int err;

    err = EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init(ctx);
    if(err <= 0) throw NULL;

    err = EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PADDING);
    if(err <= 0) throw NULL;

    size_t outLen = 0;
    err = EVP_PKEY_decrypt(
                            ctx,
                            NULL,
                            &outLen,
                            (uchar*) ui->encryptedTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().toStdString().c_str(),
                            ui->encryptedTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().size()
    );
    if(err <= 0) throw NULL;
    decrypted.resize(outLen);

    err = EVP_PKEY_decrypt(
                            ctx,
                            (uchar*) decrypted.data(),
                            &outLen,
                            (uchar*) ui->encryptedTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().toStdString().c_str(),
                            ui->encryptedTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().size()
    );
    //------------------------------------------------
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pk);

    if(err > 0) ui->decryptedTextEdit->document()->setPlainText(QString(decrypted));
    else {
            QByteArray errStr = QByteArray();
            errStr.resize(256);
            ERR_load_ERR_strings();
            ERR_error_string(err, errStr.data());
            ui->decryptedTextEdit->document()->setPlainText( QString(errStr) );
    }
}
```

Sourcecode 2. Implementation:

```
void MainWindow::rsaEncrypt()
{
    RSA *rsa = createRSAFromFile(ui->publicKeyPath->text().toStdString().c_str(), 1);

    QByteArray encrypted = QByteArray();
    encrypted.resize(2048);

    int err = RSA_public_encrypt(
                    ui->plainTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().size(),
                    (uchar*) ui->plainTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().toStdString().c_str(),
                    (uchar*) encrypted.data(),
                    rsa,
                    RSA_PADDING
    );

    RSA_free(rsa);
    if(err > 0) ui->encryptedTextEdit->document()->setPlainText( QString(encrypted) );
    else {
            QByteArray errStr = QByteArray();
            errStr.resize(256);
            ERR_load_ERR_strings();
            ERR_error_string(err, errStr.data());
            ui->encryptedTextEdit->document()->setPlainText( QString(errStr) );
    }
}

void MainWindow::rsaDecrypt()
{
    RSA *rsa = createRSAFromFile(ui->privateKeyPath->text().toStdString().c_str(), 0);

    QByteArray decrypted = QByteArray();
    decrypted.resize(2048);

    int err = RSA_private_decrypt(
                    ui->encryptedTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().size(),
                    (uchar*) ui->encryptedTextEdit->document()->toPlainText().toStdString().c_str(),
                    (uchar*) decrypted.data(),
                    rsa,
                    RSA_PADDING
    );


    RSA_free(rsa);
    if(err > 0) ui->decryptedTextEdit->document()->setPlainText( QString(decrypted) );
    else {
            QByteArray errStr = QByteArray();
            errStr.resize(256);
            ERR_load_ERR_strings();
            ERR_error_string(err, errStr.data());
            ui->decryptedTextEdit->document()->setPlainText( QString(errStr) );
    }
}

RSA *MainWindow::createRSAFromFile(const char *keyPath, int pub)
{
    FILE *keyFile = fopen(keyPath, "rb");
    if(keyFile==NULL)
    {
            return 0;
    }
    RSA *rsa = RSA_new();

    if(pub)
    {
            rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(keyFile, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
            rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(keyFile, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
    }
    fclose(keyFile);
    return rsa;
}
```

Includes and defines for both implementations:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define RSA_PADDING RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
```

Comment: Where do you get the error exactly?

Comment: [what's `RsaEncrypt` doing in `MainWindow`](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-wrong-level-of-abstraction/)?

Comment: @Theolodis: error is the return value of the functions EVP_PKEY_decrypt() and RSA_private_decrypt().

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov rsaEncrypt is in the MainWindow because this source was just a small version for testing it, I will write a class later (When the encryption and decryption is working).

Comment: @H4ckHunt3r, I'd suggest GUI-independent unit tests for that purpose

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov I tried it without gui too, but the result was the same error.. And I really have no idea how to fix this. :(

Comment: Call `SSL_library_init();`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this Code for creating a RSA-object. It definetly works. You should read the .pem file before and then call this function:

```
RSA *CryptClassRSA::createRSA(unsigned char *key, int isPublic){
    RSA *rsa = NULL;
    BIO *keybio;
    keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, -1);
    if (keybio==NULL){
        printf( "Failed to create key BIO");
        return NULL;
    }
    if(isPublic){
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
    }
    else{
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
    }
    if(rsa == NULL){
        printf( "Failed to create RSA");
    }

    return rsa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> C++ RSA decrypt error:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:lib(255):func(4095):reason(4095)

And

> ```
> int err;
> ...
> err = EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PADDING);
> if(err <= 0) throw NULL;
> ...
> ```

Its not clear to me *where* the error is happening or how you are getting the ***errstr*** output of *`error:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:lib(255):func(4095):reason(4095)`*. I picked ***`EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding`*** as the snippet because I think the return value is -2 (and it has significance as explained below).

`err` is just a return code. To get the actual error, you need to call ***`ERR_get_error`***. Maybe something like:

```
int rc;
unsigned long err;
...

rc = EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PADDING);
err = ERR_get_error();
if(rc <= 0)
{
    // err is valid
}
```

You should also visit the [`EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding.html) and [`ERR_get_error`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/ERR_get_error.html) man pages.

Often, OpenSSL will return 0 for success, so I'm not sure about ***`err <= 0`*** in some places. Also, because your error is ***`0xffff...4095`*** (and not ***`4096`***), I think you are getting the -2 return value discussed in the man page:

> EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl() and its macros return a positive value for success and 0 or a negative value for failure. In particular a return value of -2 indicates the operation is not supported by the public key algorithm.

---

Also note... If you gather your error and print it in hex:

```
rc = EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PADDING);
err = ERR_get_error();
if(rc <= 0)
{
    // err is valid
    std::cerr << std::hex << err << std::endl;
}
```

Then you can use the ***`openssl errstr 0xNNNN`*** to print it.